# Can't configure Presto resource-group in aws emr 5.33

Tags: amazon-web-services, bigdata, amazon-emr, presto

I have tried to configure it as mentioned on Presto Documentation by making two file under  etc folder `1) resource-groups.properties` and `2) resource-groups.json`. Still cluster doesn't seem to pick any user group made by me.
I have created those file under `/etc/presto/conf/` directory.

Content of resource-groups.properties

```
resource-groups.configuration-manager=file
resource-groups.config-file=etc/presto/conf/resource-groups.json
```

Content of resource-groups.json is as mentioned in this link
https://ahana.io/learn/presto/setting-up-presto-resource-groups/

I am using presto cli command to mention group.

```
presto-cli --source group1
```

Do I have to configure something in config.properties?
When i tried writing `experimental.resource-groups-enabled=true` this line in config.properties then presto server stops working.

Comment: To get more attention, please consider adding some more details such as the contents of your configuration files, specific errors you are seeing, and what else you have done to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Suraj Singh I am facing similar problem. Did it finally work for you?